# Trying to identify this potentiometer marked "B5K"

Tags: identification, potentiometer, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to identify this potentiometer as accurately as possible:

[image: Photo of potentiometer]

On the rear it says: `B5K`.

It has two rows of 3 pins each:

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,3)
```

Below are some measurements taken with my multimeter between pins 2 and 3, and the unit is: kΩ.

When taking the measurements, I was making small increments. I tried to make the same increment amount each time. But you know, I'm human and the increments were not totally perfect. I did this 4 times, see the following graphs:

[image: Measurement graph 1]

[image: Measurement graph 2]

[image: Measurement graph 3]

[image: Measurement graph 4]

Can you identify this potentiometer?

What's the nature of this potentiometer? `linear`, `logarithmic`, etc?

Where I could buy it?

Is there any other data I would need to provide, in order to properly identify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the measurements done in the original board, or after de-soldering the part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a "B" type, it should be linear.  From your plots, it's not very linear, but it's definitely not logarithmic either.

So it's a 5K linear potentiometer.  Given the tolerances, a 4.7K one would probably also work if you can't find 5K.

As per the comment by Hearth, if it's got 6 pins, it will be a dual-gang 5K pot.

Comment: Sounds like it's a double-ganged pot, too; might want to mention that.